# Mule SQLJDBC JavaKerberos authentication- classpath issue

Tags: mule, kerberos, mule-studio, mssql-jdbc

I am Using SQLJDBC to connect to MS-SQL using JavaKerberos authentication . Unfortunately  when i set following values , SQLJDBC is not looking for the files in src/main/resources , instead it expects the files to be in root (which fails in cloudhub/stand alone but works fine in studio)

`System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "sqlserverJDBC.conf");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "krb5.conf");`
Help needed !!

Thanks
Naveen H

Answer (score 0):

you will need to set the path (relative or absolute) to the conf file.

System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "src/main/resources/krb5.conf");

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/KerberosReq.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the  reply , That works in anypoint studio . If i deploy the same in cloudHub or in standalone , this will not work .

I got it working with the following changes .

```
File jaasFile = new File(classLoader.getResource(obj.getAppPropertyFile("sqlserverJDBC.conf.file")).getFile());
    String jaasConfigFilePath = jaasFile.getPath();
    System.out.println("sqlserverJDBC path : " + jaasConfigFilePath);
    obj.write(jaasConfigFilePath,strBuilder);
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", jaasConfigFilePath);
```